# After creating new API Management Service instance, why cant the built in admin account login to developer portal to approve registered applications?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

After a new instance is created, there is only a single user. I can add a second user, and that user can login to azure developer portal and register application. 
As an admin, I receive the email request which includes the link to 
http://{newAPIMS}.portal.azure-api.net/Admin

However, my login does NOT work, and even trying to reset password results in 'User does not exist'

Steps to reproduce.
Create new api management instance (which creates your email as admin)
Create second user, with different email. (Developer role)
Have the second user login to http://{newAPIMS}.portal.azure-api.net, register application.

Wiat for email to admin account, attempt to click link to approve app.

Answer (score 1):

Your account needs to be the global admin for the tenant and subscription admin. Generally this would be your onmicrosoft.com account. It's possible that you have duplicate usernames for a work account and personal account that have separate passwords and identities. Please confirm that you can register the application by yourself on that tenant by following the [app registration flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app) and tell me if you receive any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in administrator account can't login directly into Developer portal. By default there is a message about that on sign-in page:

[image]

Clicking that link will navigate you to Azure portal and from there you should be able to click either "Publisher portal" or "Developer portal" to sign-in as an admin.

Comment: Clicking on the link only redirects me to azure portals home page. Ive been granted the highest level of rights possible.Also, clicking on the link from the portal only takes me back to the page you have shown above. Its a circular loop.

Comment: As long as you have access to APIM service in Azure Portal you should be able to login as admin via buttons on service overview page. Since that's not the case, you should open support request.

Comment: @Vitally Kurokhtin, What does the user interface look like for the approval of a requested application?

Comment: @joey on a publisher portal there is "Applications" sections on the left. It has two tabs: Published applications and Submitted applications each one showing corresponding apps. From there you can click on app to view it's details and perform actions on it.